# automatic mail generation in cocoa from server side

Tags: objective-c, web-services, cocoa

I don't have any idea for generating automatic emails using cocoa from server side. In every link they have given only by using applescript. Can anyone please suggest me with some ideas for generating mails from server side? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SBSendEmail/) is an example of sending an email by using the Mail.app. Pretty sure you can send it with out a gui if thats what you need to do too.

What you ask is pretty vague, but I think this is what you were looking for. As for set mail() script which is available in something like PHP, there is none that I know of.

Comment: Thank u :) But here we have to be synchronized with Mail app. Do we have any other way to send an automatically generated email from server side?

Comment: That example uses Mail.app to send the email. What do you mean by synchronized?

Comment: The user's mail account should be valid under 'Mail' app right?

Comment: I would believe so, or at the very least have an account that is setup  in it.

Comment: So can't we do it without using Mail app?

Comment: you can, but you would need to program a whole lot more. It is not as simple as you want it to be like applescript or php.

Comment: Can you provide me any idea for implementing this?